# ls -l truncates user name and group name to 8 characters

Tags: linux, file, ls, owner

I have a users test5678x and test5678. That own files in a folder. 
with ls -l the owner name and the group are truncated so they both look the same.

```
-rw-r--r--    1 test5678 test5678         0 Jun 14 08:36 test5678file
-r--r--r--    1 test5678 test5678         0 Jun 14 08:25 test5678xfile
```

is there a way around this?

Comment: I know of `stat -c %U /path/to/file` but want to list owners of all the files.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `-w` option of `ls` to tune the width of the screen:

```
ls -w 500
```

Comment: it doesn't show the full name. According to this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1187330?start=0&tstart=0 ls uses userfromuid()  library function that only contains 8 characters of the username. So a fix may be more involved, if not non existent.

Comment: @Origami, I found [a patch written by Keith Thompson in 2000](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-fileutils/2000-10/msg00020.html). Of course, I would be very surprised if you could apply it 16 years later.

Comment: Ths POSIX standard for maximum user name length is 8 characters (technically 9 "including the terminating null")  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/limits.h.html